# Jquery .each() only replacing first found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this script which should automatically load up an Items tooltip on dom ready.

It works perfectly if I'd wish to only have the first found item to show a tooltip, but sadly that's not my goal.

The current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dbobject').each(function(){
        $(this).load('data/fetch.php?id='+ $(this).attr('tdbid'), function(){ 
        });
    });
});
```

It works perfectly for the first item, and whatever I do I seem to break the script every time!

It currently looks for any href containing tdbid="ID HERE" tag, then load up the value of the ID from fetch.php.

How can I revise this code in a way so it will look up ALL links with tdbid in it's anchor and not only first one found?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, that's an ID, and there should only be one element with that ID, so no need for `each`

Comment: `$('#dbobject')` will only match a single element, the first element with that `id` (since `id` values **must** be unique on the page). Even if you give multiple elements the same `id` (which you must not do), `$('#dbobject')` will only return a jQuery set containing the first of them. (Well, *probably* the first; browsers are free to do what they want if you give them invalid HTML.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling each on #dbobject. I assume you only have one of those. It sounds like you want to be doing `$("a[tdbid]").each(...)`

Answer (score 1):

An identity has to be unique in the page to work properly. When you select an element by id, then you will only get the first one, because there is only supposed to be one.

Instead of selecting using the id, you can select all the anchor elements that has a `tdbid` attribute:

```
$('a[tdbid]').each(function(){
```

Comment: I think I've been spending to much time in a row for not seeing this.
Thank you!